# Allowing line break at C++ operators ('::', '->', ...) in \lstinline

Tags: listings, line-breaking, characters

The following picture shows my problem:

[image]

How can I tell `\lstinline` to break lines at specific C++ operators?
For example: `FooFactory::instance()->createFoo()` should be broken as follows:

```
... text   FooFactory::
instance()->createFoo()
```

or

```
FooFactory::instance()->
createFoo() text text ...
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true
}
\lstset{literate=% I dont know what I am doing...
    {::}{::}{1\discretionary{}{}{}} % line-break at ::
    {->}{->}{1\discretionary{}{}{}} % line-break at ->
}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text \lstinline{FooFactory::instance()->createFoo()} text text
text text text text 

text text text text text text \lstinline{FooFactory::instance()->createFoo()} text text
text text text text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why this works either.  More precisely, I don't know why you need to put the \discretionary after the number instead of inside the replacement text.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% all it does for me is produce warnings
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true
    }
\lstset{literate={::}{}{0\discretionary{::}{}{::}}% line-break at ::
   {->}{}{0\discretionary{->}{}{->}}% line-break at ->
}
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text  \lstinline{FooFactory::instance()->createFoo()} text text text text text text 

text text text text text text \lstinline{FooFactory::instance()->createFoo()} text text text text text text 

\begin{lstlisting}
    FooFactory::instance()->createFoo();
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: listings]

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly for `\lstinline`, however it breaks the `lstlisting` environment. I have updated my question.

Comment: With indentation, there just isn't room for the whole line.

Comment: Many Thanks! The `0` in front of `\discretionary` did the trick. Right?

Comment: It also got rid of the extra space being added.

Comment: What is `formfeed` for? And why is there no comma as separator between the options?

Comment: Oops, that was an earlier experiment I forgot to remove.  It will now mysteriously disappear.  As for no comma, that's how the manual specified it.